# Ho do I see how many png files and their resolutions in the folders for printing into excel?

Tags: python

My folder structure is as follows

1. Dataset Folder

   - Subfolder1

     - a.png b.png c.png...
   - Subfolder2

     - a.png b.png c.png...
   - Subfolder3

     - a.png b.png c.png...
   - Subfolder4

     - a.png b.png c.png...
   - Subfolder n

     - a.png b.png c.png...

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to achieve. So you want a count of the `*.png` files in all those folders, and their resolutions. What does *"for printing into excel"* mean? As in Microsoft Excel, the spreadsheet application? You want to put these images into a spreadsheet with Python?

Comment: I want to output like; Subfolder3 has 3 images -- a.png resolution is 200x300 b.png resolution 200x300.... then i want to create a csv with this outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively find files with [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), but I've used [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.walk) and `str.endswith(".png")` to gather all the png files in all subdirectories.

The excellent [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module was used to get the resolution of the images.

```py
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image

DIR = r"C:\Dataset Folder"

results = defaultdict(list)
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(DIR):
    subdirectory = root.replace(f"{DIR}\\", "")
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            width, height = Image.open(filepath).size
            results[subdirectory].append((filename, width, height))

# Print output
for subdirectory, images in results.items():
    print(f"{subdirectory} has {len(images)} image(s):")
    for filename, width, height in images:
        print(f"{filename} resolution is {width}x{height}")
    print()

# Manually write the CSV file
with open("png files.csv", "wt") as f:
    f.write("Subdirectory,Filename,Width,Height\n") # Header
    for subdirectory, images in results.items():
        for filename, width, height in images:
            f.write(f"{subdirectory},{filename},{width},{height}\n") # Rows
```

`stdout` output:

```
Subfolder1 has 4 image(s):
a.png resolution is 640x480
b.png resolution is 640x480
c.png resolution is 300x300
d.png resolution is 300x300

Subfolder2 has 4 image(s):
a.png resolution is 300x300
b.png resolution is 300x300
c.png resolution is 300x300
d.png resolution is 300x300

Subfolder3 has 4 image(s):
a.png resolution is 300x300
b.png resolution is 300x300
c.png resolution is 26x26
d.png resolution is 300x30

Subfolder4 has 1 image(s):
a.png resolution is 256x240
```

The CSV file:

```
Subdirectory,Filename,Width,Height
Subfolder1,a.png,640,480
Subfolder1,b.png,640,480
Subfolder1,c.png,300,300
Subfolder1,d.png,300,300
Subfolder2,a.png,300,300
Subfolder2,b.png,300,300
Subfolder2,c.png,300,300
Subfolder2,d.png,300,300
Subfolder3,a.png,300,300
Subfolder3,b.png,300,300
Subfolder3,c.png,26,26
Subfolder3,d.png,300,30
Subfolder4,a.png,256,240
```

The CSV file opened with Microsoft Excel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I changed the folder path to mine, but the csv is empty although the path is correct. I couldn't understand where I made a mistake.

Comment: I don't understand how that could happen, either. So the output to `stdout` is fine, but nothing is written to the CSV file? Are there any errors? Can you post the code so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I did run the code with no error. Bu when i try to print `stdout` i got NameError.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd


DIR = r"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\works\project\ai\tenPercent" # my subfolders are in the tenPercent folder

results = defaultdict(list)
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(DIR):
    subdirectory = root.replace(f"{DIR}\\", "")   
    print(filenames)
    print(root)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            width, height = Image.open(filepath).size
            results[subdirectory].append((filename, width, height))



for subdirectory, images in results.items():
    print(f"{subdirectory} has {len(images)} image(s):")
    for filename, width, height in images:
        print(f"{filename} resolution is {width}x{height}")
    print()



with open("png_files.csv", "wt") as f:
    f.write("Subdirectory,Filename,Width,Height\n") # Header
    for subdirectory, images in results.items():
        for filename, width, height in images:
            f.write(f"{subdirectory},{filename},{width},{height}\n") # Rows
```

Comment: `stdout` is not a variable, it is the name of the buffer your console/IDE prints to. What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: i did run the code with that path with no error, but csv returns empty. Also i didnt get any output like you did.

Comment: Strange. Does the csv file have the header: _Subdirectory,Filename,Width,Height_? Put `print("Results:", results)` on the line before `for subdirectory, images in results.items():`. What is the output now?

Comment: Yeah i can see the headers. When i try to take output of results its returns;  `Results: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})`

Comment: It's not finding any `.png` images in any of the directories. Below this line `if filename.endswith(".png"):` put `print("Filename:", filename)`. What's the output?

Comment: Unless all your `.png` image files don't have the extension `.png`, then what's probably happening is your `DIR` is incorrect. On the line below `DIR = r"C:\...`, put this: `print("DIR exists:", os.path.exists(DIR))`. What's the output:

Comment: My problem was about extension. Code is working well now. thank you soo much.